# Closed: ReactJS controlled input element not updating

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs-flux, reactjs

I am new to React and still trying to wrap my head around all the concepts involved. However, I just implemented a controlled input component to test the waters and it doesn't update on input. Using ImmutableJS Record and ES6 (via BabelJS). Here's a gist of the source code https://gist.github.com/creatorrr/ec4586a861d24eeea173

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. The onChange handler was getting the wrong context bound to it and hence causing the weird errors. The solution is to bind `this` to the change handler, like so:

`<input {...} onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) }>`